# jupyter-scala install behind a proxy

Tags: scala, jupyter, jupyter-scala

I'm trying to install jupyter-scala to get a scala kernel working with jupyterlab.  I'm behind a proxy and it's timing out.  I have the http(s)_proxy host and port environment variables set properly.

Following the instructions here: https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala#jupyter-installation

Looking into jupyter-scala and coursier, I cannot find where I can set proxy settings.  Anyone know?

Thanks!

The command run: `sh -x -vvvv jupyter-scala` and the interesting bit + the error:

```
/tmp/coursier.e5brtL0K launch -r sonatype:releases -r sonatype:snapshots -i ammonite -I ammonite:org.jupyter-scala:ammonite-runtime_2.11.11:0.8.3-1 -I ammonite:org.jupyter-s
cala:scala-api_2.11.11:0.4.2 org.jupyter-scala:scala-cli_2.11.11:0.4.2 -- --id scala --name Scala
Error while downloading https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/io/get-coursier/coursier-cli_2.11/1.0.0-RC1/coursier-cli_2.11-1.0.0-RC1-standalone.jar: Connecti
on timed out (Connection timed out), ignoring it
```

also when i run `wget https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/io/get-coursier/coursier-cli_2.11/1.0.0-RC1/coursier-cli_2.11-1.0.0-RC1-standalone.jar` the jar downloads so the url is fine.

Answer (score 1):

An (ugly) solution is to download the jar by hand and then using the following command line to launch coursier:

```
java -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 \
   -cp coursier-cli_2.11-1.0.0-RC1-standalone.jar coursier.cli.Coursier
```

Comment: this almost works except you also need to add a system property -Dcoursier.mainJar=coursier-cli_2.11-1.0.0-RC1-standalone.jar